# Dynamic Sort and Group Data between Sheets

Tags: excel

I am quite new to more advanced ways of Excel, and need some advice that can point me in the right direction! I got some employee data in sheet 1 (Employers), like this:

[image]

Is there a way to automatically sort and group the data dynamically. Fro sheet 1 into sheet 2 (Employers) in the same workbook?
Like this:

[image]

**With dynamic and automatic I mean:**

- CITY and LASTNAME sorted Alphabetalcaly
- Only ACTIVE employees shuld be copied from sheet 1 to sheet 2
- If ACTIVE changes from NO to YES, they should autmaticaly be copied to sheet 2
- If NEW and ACTIVE employees are added in sheet 1, they should be copied to sheet 2
- When a NEW row is generated in sheet 2, a dropdown (STATUS) should be
  added to the end of the city row (but not to each employee row below)

I might be wrong, but it does not seem like a pivot table will work for this particular work-case. Could I somehow achieve this using formulas or do I have to create a macro?

Comment: Explore `pivot table`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can come close with a formula, if you have Office 365:

- I made the data range into a Table

  - This enables the range to be dynamic as you add/delete entries
- Create the desired headers row manually
- You will need to add the Status column with the dropdowns manually.

Then use this formula in a single cell.
The results will spill into the adjacent cells

```
=LET(x, SORT(FILTER(myTbl,myTbl[Active]="Yes"),{5,2}),
       INDEX(x,SEQUENCE(ROWS(x)),{5,1,2,3}))
```

- The first step of the formula: `x` filters and sorts the original data
- The second step rearranges the columns into your desired output order

[image]

The formula will be dynamic and respond to changes in the data without any intervention on your part.

You can adjust the appearance of the results table with conditional formatting -- still allowing a dynamic solution that will update

[image]

I used:

[image]

- Rule1: If current city is the same as the one in the next row, change font color to white (makes it invisible) or whatever your interior color is.
- Rule2: If current city is different from the one below, draw a solid border below the entire row

If you need the layout to be **exactly** as you show it in your question, then a VBA macro would be the easiest, but you would need some method of triggering its activation when you make changes in the data.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a combination of Pivot Table and some functions.
Firstly, add concatenation of name and surname to employers sheet.
***like this***
[image: like this]

Later you create this simple Pivot Table:
[image: this simple pivot table]

- City in rows and First Name + Last Name in rows.

Then you add a profession column outside of the pivot table, use the `VLOOKUP` function to get profession `(=VLOOKUP(A5;Sheet1!A:D;4;0))`.

If you are not happy with having `Name+Last Name` in one column you can split it with function or make `VLOOKUP` to employers sheet.

If you will use this solution, make sure you handle duplicates properly.